# Mobile Products listing page with multiple checkboxes

Tags: mobile, multiple-products

One of the user requirements for the app I’m developing is to display the products with its spec(real product) to allow user to add the spec to cart.

The desired outcome will be similar to the image I’ve attached. Is there any way to improve the UX? I’m worried when the number of products increases, the checkboxes and the select fields will make the view too heavy for the user to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Design Flaw

The attachment shows a list of products and only a single add to cart button. **How will a user choose a particular product and add to his cart?**

### Solution

The best way to design this app would be to have a listing page for products and a details page for each product.

- Each product in the listing page should have abstract of its details.
- On tapping a product from the list it should navigate to the product detail page.
- The product details page should show the details along with spec options and "Add to cart" button.
- A final cart page with option to remove a product or navigate back to the product page and change this spec selection.
- Optionally, in the listing page you can provide "Add to Cart" button for each product and when user taps on it either take him to the details page and ask him to choose specs or show a pop up with the spec asking him to make his selection. (Most shopping apps *eg. Amazon* have this function only in the product details page)

[image]

**Alternative**: You can also use an accordion layout or expandable cards and remove the product detail page but, if you have large number of products/details/specs the design might look heavy if they are not properly arranged. In this case, there should be a "Add to Cart" button for each product.

[image]